# Excel - How do you sort data in a single column and divide it into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which is a single column where data is mixed in with data headings like so:

```
heading 1
data
data
heading 2
data
```

Is there a way to split the headings and the data into separate columns automatically with a macro or VBA code so that the result would be:

```
heading 1    heading 2   
data         data         
data
```

Comment: How do you know what's a heading and what's data?  (Are, say, the data all numeric and headings are not?)

Comment: BruceWayne, the headings are primarily separated from the data by cell background color. However, the majority of them end with a forward slash "/". Cell color would be the primary way to separate in my particular case, but I asked my question using numbered heading examples in hopes that any solutions could have a more general application that others may be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your example that is given and assuming that the list of Headings starts in A1 with "Heading 1", put "Heading 1" in B1, "Heading 2" in C1, "Heading 3" in D1. Keep going until you have as many headings as there are in Column A, plus one extra heading (a dummy heading).

Also, add this extra dummy heading to your actual list of headings in Column A.The dummy heading need not contain any actual data.

Put this formula in Cell B2 and copy across =IFERROR(IF(OR(IF(MATCH(INDEX($A$1:$A$51,MATCH(B$1,$A$1:$A$51,0)+1,1),$A$1:$A$51,0)>=MATCH(C$1,$A$1:$A$51,0),"",INDEX($A$1:$A$51,MATCH(B$1,$A$1:$A$51,0)+ROW()-1,1))=C$1,B1=""),"",INDEX($A$1:$A$51,MATCH(B$1,$A$1:$A$51,0)+ROW()-1,1)),""), then fill down (Ctrl +D) as needed.